# Automatically create Django Profile when creating user using signals.py

Tags: python, django

I have an issue in signals.py. `Parameter 'sender' value is not used.` and `Parameter 'kwargs' value is not used.`. In my previous project, this was working fine, But in this project `User(AbstractUser)` model was introduced in models.py then this issue began.

`SIGNALS.PY`

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile, MedicalInfo


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

`Models.py`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

`VIEWS.PY`

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('public:profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'all_users/public/profile.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you customized the user the import has to be changed to `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` also you need to add your custom model to settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion this came up `from django.contrib.auth.models import get_user_model
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_user_model' from 'django.contrib.auth.models'`

Comment: it is not from models, check the answer

Comment: @bmons if we do like this: `from django.conf import settings` and we specify the `User` model like this: `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` it's going to work ?

Comment: it will work, but latest version of django it is as shown in my code